С++ Помогите с вводом и выводом кирилицы в файл
Windows. Visual studio. С++ проект универский. Надо вписать и вывести с вектора строки на кирилице. Подключала SetConsoleCP SetConsoleOutputCP 1251 и 65001,шрифт consolas и lucida console, только меню на кирилице норм выводится, в файл не вводится и не выводится русский текст. Сохраняла с кодировками, не помогло

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Нужно больше информации. Скорее всего все сохраняется, но не в той кодировке. В какой кодировке вы создаете и пробуете открывать файл? На счет кода, SetConsole... на файлы не влияет, только на консоль.

Убедитесь что файлы с кодом и с данными сохранены в UTF-8. Если компилятор - MSVC, установите /utf-8 в настройках проекта. Консоль переведите в UTF-8 режим, как описано здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1583384/215103
